# Approximating a linearized gravitational wave expression

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

[image]

This is in the context of gauge fixing condition for obtaining linearized gravitational waves. $g_{ab}=\eta_{ab}+h_{ab}$ and $h_{ab}$ is the small perturbation that stands for the gravitational wave. How does one obtain $\widetilde{g}_{ab}-g_{ab}=\nabla_a\eta_b+\nabla_b\eta_a$? I cannot find a way how to obtain the covariant derivative... Could anyone please explain?